# DBeaver query on Snowflake results in "SQL Error [604] [57014]: SQL execution canceled" if lasting around 5 minutes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

We are using dbeaver quite happily with Snowflake back end but I can't execute queries that last around 5 minutes or more.

It looks like there is sometimeout somewhere and the execution seems cancelled by DBeaver.

The error message is "SQL Error [604] [57014]: SQL execution canceled"

Any idea how I could instruct DBeaver to wait for whatever it takes?

[image: DBeaver Errors and timeouts]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because the [STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#statement-timeout-in-seconds) parameter has been set to cancel all queries after they run for 5 minutes or more.

You can check what it is set to by running this in dbeaver.

```
show parameters like '%STATEMENT_TIMEOUT%' in session;
```

Comment: Indeed, it is set to 1728000 which is about 3mns.
Where can I change this setting?

Comment: I think I found it!

Window / Preferences / SQL Processing / SQL Statement Timeout was 300 seconds

Comment: Hmmm, maybe dbeaver was overwriting the default timeout that is set by Snowflake for your session.

Comment: Looks like it indeed